# Handle segmentation fault accessing non-existent command line argument

Tags: c, command-line

I'm making a program in C in linux environment. Now, program runs with arguments which I supply in the command line.

For example:

```
./programName -a 45 -b 64
```

I  wanted to handle the case when my command line parameters are wrongly supplied. Say, only 'a' and 'b' are valid parameters and character other than that is wrong. I handled this case. But suppose if my command line parameter is like this:

```
./programName -a 45 -b
```

It gives segmentation fault(core dumped). I know why it gives because there is no arguments after b. But how can I handle this situation such that when this condition arrives, I can print an error message on screen and exit my program.

Comment: use getopt(3). (`man 3 getopt` for details)

Comment: You do not print error messages to the screen.  You print them to stderr.  Although stderr is often a tty, it is a mistake to think they are identical.

Comment: There is more than one way to handle options (which is what these are). How do you do it now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [the main function wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_function):

> The parameters argc, argument count, and argv, argument vector, respectively

So you can use your argc parameter to check whether or not you have the right number of arguments. If you don't have 4, handle it and proceed without segfault.

Answer (score 0):

You can, and quite probably should, use [`getopt()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getopt.html) or its GNU brethren [`getopt_long()`](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Getopt.html).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int b = 0;
    int a = 0;
    int opt;

    while ((opt = getopt(argc, argv, "a:b:")) != -1)
    {
        switch (opt)
        {
        case 'a':
            a = atoi(optarg);
            break;
        case 'b':
            b = atoi(optarg);
            break;
        default:
            fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s -a num -b num\n", argv[0]);
            exit(1);
        }
    }

    if (a == 0 || b == 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: you did not provide non-zero values for both -a and -b options\n", argv[0]);
        exit(1);
    }

    printf("a = %d, b = %d, sum = %d\n", a, b, a + b);
    return(0);
}
```

You can make the error detection more clever as you wish, not allowing repeats, spotting extra arguments, allowing zeros through, etc.  But the key point is that `getopt()` will outlaw your problematic invocation.

We can't see what went wrong with your code because you didn't show it, but if you go accessing a non-existent argument (like `argv[4]` when you run `./programName -a 42 -b`), then you get core dumps. There are those who write out option parsing code by hand; such code is more vulnerable to such problems than code using `getopt()` or an equivalent option parsing function.